# Seemingly weird logic of HTTP requests in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-crispy-forms

I have a problem that I solved but the fact that I don't understand how tells me that there is something basic I'm missing. Hope somebody can help me.

So I have a class based update view with inline formsets. I use crispy forms to render the view. The code below was first working, then for some reason it started giving me `Management form missing` error when just trying to load the update page in my browser.

```
#views.py:
class CaveUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model=Cave
    form_class=CaveForm
    template_name='caves/cave_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
      context = super(CaveUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      entrance_helper = EntranceFormSetHelper()
      context['entrance_helper'] = entrance_helper
      if self.request.GET:
        context['entrance_formset']=EntranceInlineFormSet(instance=self.object)
      else:
        context['entrance_formset']=EntranceInlineFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
```

After wrecking my brains out, I changed the last 4 lines of the `get_context_data` function to this and everything was solved:

```
      if self.request.POST:
        context['entrance_formset']=EntranceInlineFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
      else:
        context['entrance_formset']=EntranceInlineFormSet(instance=self.object)
```

So my question is, how are these two expressions not equivalent? Is there another type of request I somehow make my browser send by refreshing?

Comment: Show us the template code that is rendering the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if self.request.GET` doesn't mean "if the request is a GET" - and `if self.request.POST` doesn't mean "if the request is a POST". They are using boolean operators on the GET and POST dictionaries respectively - and in Python, dicts are boolean False if they're empty and True otherwise.

So, your calls are actually asking "does the request have some querystring parameters", which may or may not be true whether or not the request is a GET, and "does the request have a body", which will not be true with an empty POST.

If you actually want to check the type of the request,you should explicitly check `if request.method == 'GET'` (or `'POST'`).